# Enhancing Dijkstra's Algorithm for Navigation

Tags: c#, path, dijkstra, shortest

I have written an implementation for Dijkstra's algorithm that integrate with ArcGIS, the implementation is written in C#.net.

I have reached a solving time of about 20 seconds for a graph with 80,000 nodes (worst case time), I have used a priority queue implementation from Alexey Kurakin (thanks a lot) and I think there is nothing I can do to enhance this time.

I have several questions:

1. Is this an acceptable time?
2. How can I improve it?
3. Is writing the solution in another platform (I think of Delphi or C++) can enhance the time?

Best Regards.

Comment: 1. depends on what you think is acceptable.
2. difficult to say without seeing some code
3. maybe, depends

Comment: I don't think this is fast. Why is it that slow? Using an in-memory graph will probably help a lot!

Comment: Hello, I had to do some tweaks to the original Dijsktra algorithm, the result is great, I solved a 90,000 node graph in less than 2 seconds